# Show that $\ker(T)=\{\varphi _n\mid\lambda_n\neq 0\}^\perp $

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

Let $T:H \to H$ be defined as $Tx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lambda_n \langle x,\varphi _n \rangle \varphi _n$, given that $\{\varphi _n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is an orthonormal  sequence (not necessarily a basis) and $\{\lambda_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of numbers (which may be complex if the Hilbert space is complex).

Show that $\ker (T)=\{\varphi _n\mid\lambda_n\neq 0\}^\perp $.

What does this $\{\}^\perp $ notation mean? Do I need to show that $\varphi _n$ are perpendicular to each other? If so how?

Comment: This notation means take the set of vectors such that the $n$th coefficient is nonzero, and find the orthogonal complement of that. I.e., $\operatorname{ker}(T)^\perp = \{ f \in H \mid \left\langle f,g \right\rangle = 0 \text{ for all } g \in \operatorname{ker}(T)\}$.

Comment: What is an orthogonal complement?

Comment: It is the set I described -- the Hilbert space comes with an inner product, and two vectors are said to be orthogonal if their inner product is 0. The orthogonal complement of a set $S$, written $S^\perp$, is the set of vectors that have 0 inner product with everything from $S$. Taking the standard inner product on $\Bbb{R}^2$, the $x$-axis has the $y$-axis as its orthogonal complement. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: Almost . does every Element of the set $S$ has to be orthogonal to every element in the set $S^\perp$?

Comment: Yes. For any set $S \subset H$, we define $S^\perp = \{ v \in H \mid \left\langle v,w \right\rangle = 0 \forall w \in S\}$. Thus, for any $w \in S$ and any $v \in S^\perp$, we have $\left\langle v,w \right\rangle = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $S^\perp$ means $\{x\in H\mid \langle x,y\rangle=0,\text{ for all }y\in S\}$.

Let $x\in\ker T$; you need to prove that, for every $m$ with $\lambda_m\ne0$, you have $\langle x,\varphi_m\rangle=0$.

You know that $\sum_n\lambda_n\langle x,\varphi_n\rangle\varphi_n=0$, so also
$$
\Bigl<\sum_n\lambda_n\langle x,\varphi_n\rangle\varphi_n,\varphi_m\Bigr>
=0
$$
Since the series converges, you can deduce that
$$
0=\sum_n\langle\lambda_n\langle x,\varphi_n\rangle\varphi_n,\varphi_m\rangle
=\sum_n\lambda_n\langle x,\varphi_n\rangle\,\langle\varphi_n,\varphi_m\rangle=
\lambda_m\langle x,\varphi_m\rangle
$$
Since $\lambda_m\ne0$, by assumption, it follows that $\langle x,\varphi_m\rangle=0$.

Conversely, you need to show that, if $\langle x,\varphi_m\rangle=0$ whenever $\lambda_m\ne0$, then $x\in\ker T$, meaning that $\sum_n\lambda_n\langle x,\varphi_n\rangle\varphi_n=0$. Can you show it?

Comment: How come I know that $\sum_n \lambda_n \langle x,\varphi_n \rangle \varphi_n=0$?

Comment: @moshe Because $x\in\ker T$, that is, $Tx=0$.

Comment: Does $x\in ker T \implies Tx \to 0$?

Comment: @moshe It's the definition of $\ker T$.

Comment: @ egreg I tried showing the conversely part to no avail. First of all I didnt get your transition with $\sum_n \langle \lambda_n \langle x, \varphi_n \rangle \varphi_n,\varphi_m \rangle =\sum_n \lambda_n \langle   x, \varphi_n \rangle \langle \varphi_n,\varphi_m \rangle $. Can you kindly expend?. Second of all I tried going by $\langle x,\varphi_m \rangle=0 \implies \lambda_m \langle x,\varphi_m \rangle=0 \forall \lambda_m \neq 0$ but I don't know if I can simply convert that to a series.. How should I go about it?

Comment: @moshe Set $a_n=\lambda_n\langle x,\varphi_n\rangle$; then you have $\sum_n\langle a_n\varphi_n,\varphi_m\rangle=\sum_n a_n\langle \varphi_n,\varphi_m\rangle$ by linearity. For the converse: the series $\sum_n\lambda_n\langle x,\varphi_n\rangle$ has all terms $0$.

Comment: if $\sum_n \lambda_n  \langle x,\varphi_n \rangle=0$ I can simply multiply everything with $\varphi_n$ and get there?

Comment: @moshe Sorry, I forgot some terms: the last series should be $\sum_n\lambda_n\langle x,\varphi_n\rangle\varphi_n$, but the terms are zero anyway.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: You need to use the fact that $\phi_n$ is orthonormal. That is, $\left\langle \phi_n,\phi_m \right\rangle = \left\lbrace \begin{array}{cc} 
0 & n \neq m \\
1 & n = m
\end{array} \right.$. Start by supposing that $f \in \ker(T)$ so that $T(f) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_n \left\langle f,\phi_n \right\rangle \phi_n=0$. What can you say if $f$ is one of the $\phi_m$s? Try working with the definition of orthogonal.